# Laravel 5 Constant define

Tags: php, laravel-5, constants

I tried all the options. Still, it is showing "Constant expression contains invalid operations". I am using Laravel 5.5, Please Help. I need to define table name in constant and use it in Model.

I wrote in Model:

```
protected $table = Config::get('constants.dbTable.EMAILTEMPLATE');
```

And In constant.php inside Config:

```
return [ 'langs' => 
    [ 
        'es' => 'www.domain.es', 
        'en' => 'www.domain.us' // etc 
    ], 
    'siteTitle' => 'HD Site', 
    'pagination' => 5, 
    'tagLine' => 'Do the best', 
    'dbTable'=>[ 
        'EMAILTEMPLATE' => 'stmd_emailTemplate'
    ] 
];
```

I want to use `emailTemplate` table.

Comment: What have you tried. Can you post the code here.

Comment: I wrote in Model
protected $table = Config::get('constants.dbTable.EMAILTEMPLATE');
And In constant.php inside Config
return [
    'langs' => [
        'es' => 'www.domain.es',
        'en' => 'www.domain.us'
        // etc
    ],
 'siteTitle' => 'HD Site',
 'pagination' => 5,
 'tagLine' => 'Do the best',
 'dbTable'=>[
  'EMAILTEMPLATE'=>'stmd_emailTemplate']
];
I want to use emailTemplate table

Comment: Have a look at the solution given in the link. May be that might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40827870/constant-expression-contains-invalid-operations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constant expression contains invalid operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40827870/constant-expression-contains-invalid-operations)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you have posted in the comment, you are trying to assign a value into a property in your model but you are assigning it too early (assumed from the keyword `protected`.) You can't do this:

```
class SomeModel extends Model
{
    protected $someProperty = config('some.value'); // Too early!
}
```

because you are trying to initialize a property that requires a run-time interpretation.

There's a workaround; use your constructor.

```
class SomeModel extends Model
{
    protected $someProperty; // Define only...

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(); // Don't forget this, you'll never know what's being done in the constructor of the parent class you extended
        $this->someProperty = config('some.value');
    }
}
```