# PHP if(!@include_once()) doesn't work

Tags: php

This was working and then it stopped. That was in version 7.2.6 the latest.

```
if(!@include_once('config.php')) {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

So we've downgraded to 7.1.9 but it doesn't work there as well.

There is no error thrown, nothing. Just a blank screen. It's as if it's not even there...

If I echo something before that, it works. If I echo something after this, nothing happens.

Why is this happening?

Comment: So what does your http servers error log file reveal what is happening?

Comment: @arkascha Nothing in the PHP log file `/var/log/php_errors.log`. HTTP returns 200. Unbelievable. Not seen anything like this before with PHP.

Comment: try with removing @

Comment: @pradeep `Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations`.

Comment: Of course there's no error thrown! You suppressed it with @

Comment: there must be something wrong in config.php

Comment: @GordonM Okay...I need to throw an error in case the file cannot be included. If the @ is removed it doesn't echo.

Comment: So maybe the call works, but the error is thrown in the included file.. Doesn't the error show a file and line number?

Comment: Also, if you want to thrown an error if a file cannot be included, you can use `require` or `require_once`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40827870/constant-expression-contains-invalid-operations

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try the advice around "example #4" on this page and see if that makes a difference?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

E.g.

```
if ((@include_once 'config.php') === FALSE) { 
    echo "failed";
}
```

By the way: as other's have said, `@` suppresses PHP warnings/errors for the line of code where it's applied.

My interpretation of your question is that you have used `@` deliberately to suppress the engine's warning and echo your own message instead. If you removed the `@` and the include failed, I'd expect to see the warning message output if errors are set to show, AND the word 'failed' should still be `echo`ed afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

what, exactly, do you think `@` does? it suppresses errors. so when you say `There is no error thrown, nothing`, this is totally expected, because if there is any errors, @ probably suppress them. remove the @, and if you can't trust your php.ini settings, do an ini_set call too, also set in some debug prints, eg

```
ini_set("error_reporting","-1");
echo "before include.";
if(!include_once('config.php')) {
    echo 'failed';
}
echo "after include";
```

then check your error logs after it executed.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it.

```
if (!(@include 'config.php')) { die(json_encode(array('error'=>true))); }
```

I need the error to be suppressed because I wan't to handle the error without breaking my script—in a way that the other end know's it's an error and will inform the front-end user.