# Automatic product insert via soap on WooCommerce product creation

Tags: php, wordpress, soap, woocommerce, product

I have a billing program and to connect that program to my online store in wordpress i used a plugin but now i've been requested to do the following update :

- Whenever we create a product on woocommerce it creates automatically on the billing program aswell

i asked the billing program support for help to do this and they gave me the following example

```
 $result = $soap->authenticate( $API_KEY );
 $APISession = $result[1];
 
 
 $ref          = "002";
 $designation  = "Produto de teste";
 $shortName    = "Ptest";
 $tax          = "23";
 $obs          = "teste";
 $isService    = "0";
 $hasStocks    = "0";
 $active       = "1";
 $shortDesc    = "Descricao 123";
 $longDesc     = "Descricao longa, teste 123.";
 $price        = "100";
 $vendorRef    = "";
 $ean          = "";
 

 $product = $soap->insertProduct( $APISession, $ref, $designation, $shortName, $tax, $obs, $isService, $hasStocks, $active, $shortDesc, $longDesc, $price, $vendorRef, $ean);
```

But thats not what i want since we insert the parameters manually on this example and i want that automatically, i explained this to the support of the billing program but they said they couldn't help me with that, so i'm asking here with the hope that someone can help me on this.

Note : These parameters are the billing program parameters and i want to fill these parameter with what comes from the woocommerce product, i am using a webhook to call the function "insertProduct"

Answer (score 1):

The hook `woocommerce_new_product` is triggered when a product is created, so it's the hook you need. So you don't need a webhook, as soap is going to do the job.

Now in the code below you will need to define variables `$soap` and `$API_KEY`.

Also note that in WooCommerce Products, the variables `$shortName`, `$tax`, `$obs`, `$isService`, `$vendorRef`, `$ean` doesn't exits.

Your code should be something like:

```
// On product creation
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_product', 'woocommerce_create_product_callback', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_create_product_callback( $product_id, $product ) {
    // First define variables $soap and $API_KEY
    $soap       = ; // <== To be defined !
    $API_KEY    = ; // <== To be defined !
    
    // Connect
    $result     = $soap->authenticate( $API_KEY );
    $APISession = $result[1];

    if( $APISession ) {
        
        // Product data
        $status             = $product->get_status();
        $name               = $product->get_name();
        $description        = $product->get_description();
        $short_descr        = $product->get_short_description();
        $parent_id          = $product->get_parent_id();
        $menu_order         = $product->get_menu_order();
        $date_created       = $product->get_date_created()->getOffsetTimestamp();
        $date_created_gmt   = $product->get_date_created()->getTimestamp();
        $slug               = $product->get_slug();
        $author_id          = get_post_field ('post_author', $product_id);
        
        // Product meta data (and post terms)
        $type               = $product->get_type();
        $tax_class          = $product->get_tax_class();
        $stock_status       = $product->get_stock_status();
        $price              = $product->get_price();
        $sku                = $product->get_sku();
        
        // Special
        $active             = $product->get_status() ==='publish' ? '1' : '0';
        $hasStocks          = $product->is_in_stock() ? '1' : '0';
         
        // Undefined (not defined in WooCommerce
        $shortName  = '';
        $tax        = '';
        $obs        = '';
        $isService  = '0';
        $vendorRef  = ''; // May be the author ID
        $ean        = ''; // May be the SKU
        
        // Send data and insert product
        $soap->insertProduct( $session, $product_id, $name, $shortName, $tax, $obs, $isService, $hasStocks, $active, $short_descr, $description, $price, $vendorRef, $ean);
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I Was wondering if i put this code in a code snippet instead functions.php, it would have the same effect ?

Comment: Yes im still testing that's why i didnt mark it as correct, i am using a webhook so i don't need that "add_action" am i right ?

Comment: @HugoAndré I think that you don't need that webhook, as it's WooCommerce that is going to trigger the action inserting a product to the billing program when a product is created on WooCommerce… So my complete code should do the trick, but you need to set correctly the SOAP part and every variable that the billing program needs through your `insertProduct()` method. May be ask again the support of the billing program, adding the link to this answer…

Comment: I'm trying in a lot of different ways and unfortunately isnt working, maybe because the billing program i would guess

Comment: `Constant expression contains invalid operations in /home/vossa2020shirts/public_html/insertProduct.php on line 5`

It gives me this error, do you know what can it be ? 

Line 5 : 

`private $soap = new soapclient( $WS_URL );`

Comment: @HugoAndré I am not a SOAP but see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171546/php-error-fatal-error-constant-expression-contains-invalid-operations) or [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40827870/constant-expression-contains-invalid-operations) related to *"Constant expression contains invalid operations in…"* error.

Comment: This is giving me this error : `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wc_get_product() in /insertProduct.php:31` How should i proceed ?