# How to initialize instance properties?

Tags: php, oop

I have sample code in my Class:

```
public $themePath = "layouts/inbox/";

public $theme     = $this->themePath."theme-limitless.";

public $inboxView = $this->theme."inbox";
```

And here my code not work. I must save my theme name in one var and path to theme in another var and use view using theme name. Now I have error:

```
Constant expression contains invalid operations:

public $theme     = $this->themePath."theme-limitless."; // Error line
```

Generaly I must get path in var `$inboxView`:

```
$inboxView = "layouts/inbox/theme-limitless.inbox";
```

Comment: Probably duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40171696/7415107

Comment: Here is a thought: stop using public visibility for object's attributes.

Comment: Ok, then I'll private or protected object's attributes @tereško

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initializate class properties in `__construct` method:

```
class MyClass
{
    public $themePath = "layouts/inbox/";
    public $theme;
    public $inboxView;

    function __construct() {
        $this->theme     = $this->themePath . "theme-limitless.";
        $this->inboxView = $this->theme . "inbox";
    }

}
```

Comment: No. This is wrong. Your code is violating [OCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).