# PHP: Constant expression contains invalid operations

Tags: php

I am trying to include `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` into a constant which I will use to define the path.

However I get an error thrown: `Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations`

```
const config_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'folder/';
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Error : Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171546/php-error-fatal-error-constant-expression-contains-invalid-operations)

Comment: Use `define('config_path', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'folder/');` because you can't concatenate strings using `const`. Also, declaring a constant in uppercase is a common practice.

Comment: first read this "http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php" then the constants are similar as static you can not make a constant equal as a var because when their are created the var not exist yet

Answer (score 1):

You should use
    define('config_path', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'folder/');
As const would be evaluated at compile time where as define would be evaluated at run time. So using $_SERVER variable with const would casue the error.