# Assigning returned data to a variable from function with PHP and PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have a problem with classes in PHP, I want to assign values received from the database to a private variable so that I can then use them in class functions. But in doing so I get the error:

> Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in ..\database.php on line 21

Here is my code:

```
class Ustawienia {
    private $current_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    private $uprawnienia = get_premissions();       //here i get a fatal error

    private function get_premissions() {
        $query_premissions = OpenCon()->prepare("SELECT * FROM uprawnienia WHERE id_pracownicy = :id");
        $query_premissions -> bindValue(':id', $current_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query_premissions -> execute();
        return $query_premissions -> fetch();
    }

    public function dostep_ustawienia() {
        if($uprawnienia['dostep_ustawienia']) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I tried to change return to echo but i didn't helped.
How can i achieve that? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can't directly assign function results in classes. That's what constructors are for.

Comment: By the way, this is where your next error will be: `if($uprawnienia['dostep_ustawienia'])`. Please read more about using classes and their properties.

Comment: Read more details here: [PHP Error : Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171546/php-error-fatal-error-constant-expression-contains-invalid-operations)

Comment: So i have to fetch data from db in constructor? Is is the correct way of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign data directly to private variable

```
$this->uprawnienia  = $query_premissions->fetch();
```

And then use this private variable:

```
if($this->uprawnienia['dostep_ustawienia']) return true;
```