# PHP typed property, how to define default value for object

Tags: php, oop

I have a class with typed property object. I need to define default empty value for that property:

This doesn't work:

```
public object $doctor = new \stdClass();
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: "This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value" From the Docs.

Comment: Either set it in constructor or in `__get()`.  Or possible check it and instantiate it when needed to use it.

Comment: From the docs:  "Typed properties must be initialized before accessing, otherwise an Error is thrown."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible and the error you get (`Constant expression contains invalid operations`) explains why: in PHP the properties can only be initialized with constant expressions. You can't use any function calls, variables or an expression producing a new object instance like in your case.

See more details here:
[PHP Error : Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171546/php-error-fatal-error-constant-expression-contains-invalid-operations)

As a workaround I'd suggest initializing the property in the constructor

Answer (score 1):

Just declare a new class instance and fill
$ obj = new stdClass ();

public object $doctor = new stdClass();

$doctor->name="namedoctor"

$doctor->titles= array('doc', 'specialist');