# How to call a private variable for concatenation inside a class

Tags: php

Please help me to understand this:

```php
1 <?php
2 class test{
3   private $a = "a";
4   private $b = $a."b";
5   
6   function __construct(){
7     echo $this->b;
8   }
9 }
```

I get `Constant expression contains invalid operations on line 4`

Why? I tried also with $this->a but it also do not work.

Please explain it to me.

*Update*

For some strange reason this works

```php
class test{
  private const a = "a";
  private $b = self::a."b";
    
  function __construct(){
    echo $this->b;
  }
}
```

I can remember now that it does not work.
But can someone please explain it to me.

Comment: You can't perform operations in class property declaration. If you want to change the value of `b` to be `a` plus something, do it in the constructor.

Comment: @El_Vanja thank you. That's really bad news.

Comment: Honestly, it seems like you shouldn't even have the `b` property, only a getter that takes `a` and appends whatever you need. Because if you change `a`, then you also need to change `b` if it's a property.

Comment: After the edit, you concatenate two *constant* expressions. In the first one, you used a variable.

Comment: @El_Vanja so operations with constants are permitted but operations with variables not?

Comment: Exactly, because it seems variable values aren't resolved yet at that point during compilation. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171546/php-error-fatal-error-constant-expression-contains-invalid-operations).

Answer (score 0):

The property declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value ([->PHP-manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)). This

```
private $b = $this->a."b";
```

throw a 'Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations..' because $this->a is not a constant. The PHP parser cannot check whether $this->a always remains constant. For PHP, $this->a is generally a variable.

That, however, works flawlessly.

```
class test
{
  private const a = "a";
  private $b = self::a."b";
}
```

self::a and "b" are constants.