# PHP get B class static property from A in class declaration

Tags: php, static

I have two classes:

```
public class B {
    public static $fields = [
        'name',
        'descripion'
    ];
}


public class A {
    public static $fields = [
        'name',
        'descripion',
        'subFields' => B::$fields
    ];
}
```

but when I try to get the $fields var from B that way I get the error: `Constant expression contains invalid operations`

Is there another way to do it or is just impossible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Error : Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171546/php-error-fatal-error-constant-expression-contains-invalid-operations)

Comment: Maybe a `get_fields()` method in `B`?