# Using Language from Model in Module of CodeIgniter 4.1 for form validation messages

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, localization, hmvc

I need integrate diferent languages for my form validation messages. I using form validation in my Model class and a file in my Language directory inside my Module. I'm working in HMVC pattern. Here some of my code:

In my ShopsModel file:

```
 protected $validationRules = [
   "name" => "required|min_length[4]|max_length[80]",
   "legalName" => "required|min_length[4]|max_length[80]|is_unique[shops.legalName]"
 ]; 

 protected $validationMessages = [
      "name" => [
      "required" => "Nombre es requerido",
        //"required" =>  lang('Shops.nameRequired'),  --My Test for load messages from Languague File
      "min_length" => "Minimum length of name should be 4 chars",
      "max_length" => "Maximum length of name should be 80 chars"
        ],
    "legalName" => [
      "required" => "legalName is required",
      "is_unique" => "Ya existe otro registro con el mismo nombre",
      "min_length" => "Minimum length of name should be 4 chars",
      "max_length" => "Maximum length of name should be 80 chars"
        ]
];
```

In my Languague File:

```
return [

    'name'          => 'Nombre:',
    'phName'        => 'Nombre corto',
    'nameRequired'  => 'Nombre es requerido',
    'phLegalName'   => 'Nombre registrado',
    
];
```

If I uncomment the line commented in my ShopsModel file I get This error:

**Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations**

There are another way for implement this? Whatever help is wellcome

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171546/php-error-fatal-error-constant-expression-contains-invalid-operations). You can solve your problem just by move your `$validationRules` to the function that handles the validation:

```
function validateMessages(){
  $validationMessages = [
      "name" => [
      "required" => "Nombre es requerido",
      "required" =>  lang('Shops.nameRequired'),
      "min_length" => "Minimum length of name should be 4 chars",
      "max_length" => "Maximum length of name should be 80 chars"
        ],
    "legalName" => [
      "required" => "legalName is required",
      "is_unique" => "Ya existe otro registro con el mismo nombre",
      "min_length" => "Minimum length of name should be 4 chars",
      "max_length" => "Maximum length of name should be 80 chars"
        ]
  ];
  // other code is here
}
```