# How to set Codigniter 4 Email Config from Env variable?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use environment variables to configure my app.
Thus, I try to set the email configuration from my `.env` file.

```php
<?php

namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;

class Email extends BaseConfig
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $fromEmail = $_ENV['FROMMAIL'];

    ...
}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations
```

How can I assign a ENV variable to a class variable?

What I tried as well is:

```php
<?php

namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;

class Email extends BaseConfig
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $fromEmail = "test";

    ...

    function __construct()
    {
       $this->fromMail = $_ENV['FROMMAIL'];
    }
}
```

where `$_ENV['FROMMAIL'] = "test@mail.com";`. But this is using the value "test" instead of my environment variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40171713/4804629

Comment: I already saw that post, but the solution there is, to remove the `static` declaration. I have no static variable, do I?