# How to call a Variable in Models in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-searchable

I am trying to call a variable in my Models/Images.php which is for a very good reason but cannot.

My variable `$langtitle = 'title'.config('app.LANG_COLUMN_CODE');` which I want to use instead of `'title'` within `protected $searchable`

Here is my whole code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Http\Controllers\Traits\Search;

class Images extends Model
{
    use Search;
    protected $guarded = array();
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'description', 'categories_id', 'metakeywords', 'hash', 'subgroup','subcategories_id'];

        protected $searchable = [
            'title',
            'metakeywords',
            'subgroup'
        ];
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User')->first();
    }
     public function category() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Categories', 'categories_id');
     }
      public function subcategories() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Subcategories', 'subcategories_id');
     }
      public function tags() {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Images', 'metakeywords');
     }
}
```

I get errors like **Constant expression contains invalid operations**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Error : Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171546/php-error-fatal-error-constant-expression-contains-invalid-operations)

Comment: I don’t see your variable being used in the model anywhere. Can you supply a sample code what it is your trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $searchable is getting called somewhere, better to use it directly where this $searchable is gettinh called.

See for `$this->searchable` and replace with:

```
$langtitle.",".'subgroup, metakeywords';
```

**Hint**: As I can understand, this might be in Search Traits!

Comment: Well it worked!!